# Cannot assign "nan"/empty value in np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, fillna

I'm trying to assign an empty cell (blank/nan) in my "np.where" condition to my pandas dataframe, but nothing seems to work.

The reason for this is to run fillna,ffill on the missing values.

**Np.Where code:**

```
df['x'] = np.where(df['y']>0.05,1,np.nan)
```

**Fillna code:**

```
df['x'] = df['x'].fillna(method="ffill")
```

Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `Cannot specify both 'value' and 'method'.` means you can't define `value=0` and `method='ffill')`. It's either `0` or `ffill`.

Comment: Yes, thanks.
Any idea on how to assign empty cells in np.where?

Comment: How is this falling short of your expectations?

Comment: It works in the way that it does assign value of 1 to row where condition is met, and "nan" where it is not. The "nan" however is not a blank cell, but just the string "nan"- i.e. my next code (fillna) does not recognize these as blank cells to be filled.

Comment: Are the values a numeric type? Can you add sample data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I solved it with pandas.NA (see answer below). Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using `pandas.NA` instead which `fillna`, for some reason, recognizes as blanks to fill with `ffill`

**Fix:**

```
df['x'] = np.where(df['y']>0.05,1,pd.NA)
df['x'] = df['x'].fillna(method="ffill")
```

Answer (score 0):

this line of code works:
`df['x'] = np.where(df['y']>0.05,1,np.nan)`
just remove the unneeded paratheses in the right

Comment: It works in the way that it does assign value of 1 to row where condition is met, and "nan" where it is not. The "nan" however is not a blank cell, but just the string "nan"- i.e. my next code (fillna) does not recognize these as blank cells to be filled.
The extra parentheses was just a typo here in the forum.